# Read text and use it from a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If some of them are match i would like to mark the matched words.
Show on the website the words with different color to the user.

```
var main = document.getElementById("selectedItem").innerText;
var opinionTargets = ["screen", "cover", "size", "waterproof", "voice", "light", "price", "color"];
var words = main.split(' ');

$(".highlight").each(function () {
for (i = 0; i < main.length; i++){
  for (j = 0; j < opinionTargets.length; j++) {
    if (words[i] == opinionTargets[j]) {
        var target = words[i];
        $(target).css('color', 'yello');
    }
  }
 }
```

1) Matched words change color in the text that i have retrieved from "selectedItem id"
(div class= "highlight" id= "selectedItem")

Answer (score 0):

You can't target specific words with a selector.

You need to modify the HTML of the element so that the word is wrapped in an element (e.g. `<em>screen</em>`) and then you can target the element (or just have a predefined style for it in the CSS).